# Way to seperate text and question from text area box in HTML

Tags: html

I have this issue. I have written this HTML code, but I am unable to align between the question, yes/no buttons and text area box. My question has huge space from yes/no buttons, but when I drag the text area box and making it smaller, the question and yes/no buttons come closer as I wanted it to look. How can I fix this issue so my question is next to the yes/no buttons and box is underneath and doesn't move when I drag to make it bigger or smaller?
[image: photo of html and css result]

```
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
 <tr>        
    <td class="data_yy">
       <input type="radio" name="jack" id="jack" value="Y" onclick="hideShowJacks('Y');"/><label>Yes</label> 
       <input type="radio" name="jack" id="jack" value="N" checked onclick="hideShowJacks('N');"/><label>No</label>
   </td>
       <td class="data_xx"> Are are taking English class in fall?</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>
       <textarea cols="120" rows="5" maxLenghth="20" class="resizable" name="jack" id="jack">    </textarea>
          <div class="plaintext" style="justify:left" id="jack">&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you can take a screenshot of your computer screen. I recommend you never take photo of your screen with an external device.

Comment: @pg_max: Hey, I added an answer, let me know if this helps!

Comment: @canbax- yea, you are right; totally makes sense, but for privacy i couldn't use my work laptop and had to use my own personal ,and to get that screen shot that was only option I had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is a table, and you have two cells in the *first row*, and only one cell in the *second row*.  You'll want that second cell to have `colspan="2"` as a property...

```
<td colspan="2">
```

And then, for the second part of your issue ("so my question [text] is next to the yes/no buttons"), you'll want to change the first yes/no cell to have `<nobr>` so it doesn't linebreak, and also set `width="1"`...

```
<td class="data_yy" width="1">
```

Made a [quick working demo](https://jsbin.com/pimifoq/edit?html,output).

Does this look right?

[image: Solution image]

Comment: @HoldOffHunger- Thank you. So I see your screen shot and tried the demo, and it looks fine, but mine some reason the text area box disappears when i add some of the suggestions you mentioned. I am not sure if it is anything to do with my css stick to it.

Comment: @pg_max - Hey, thanks for getting back to me!  Hrm, maybe you're running into a typo?  Sometimes dropping a `<` or `>` will cause an element to disappear.  You could always try copying/pasting directly from the working demo to your code.

Comment: @pg_max - Let me know if you find a working solution, or if this ended up helping you out!  Marking it as correct would help others if it did.

Comment: unfortunately, I see the same issue. As I mentioned earlier I do not see the text box area after modified those. I am trying to see what could be the issue.

Comment: Awesome you are totally right. I forgot to put ">" at <td colspan="2">. Thank you very much. Now it solved the issue.